If $f$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$ are continuous, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is continuous?
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that both $f$ and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$ are continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ also continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$?
Precise statement: Let
$$g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:(x,y)\mapsto\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+\varepsilon,y)-f(x,y)}{\varepsilon},$$
and let:
$$h:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:(x,y)\mapsto\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{g(x+\varepsilon,y)-g(x,y)}{\varepsilon},$$
then, assuming $g$ and $h$ both exist, if $f$ and $h$ are continuous, is $g$ also continuous?
This looks quite elementary but unusual as we don't deal with any $C^k$ function. I am quite lost with this one. Any help?

$f_y$ often means $\partial f/\partial y$. Your $df/dx$ is what most would call $\partial f/\partial x$; I recommend this notation

So I'd phrase it as: if $f$ and $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}$ are continuous, is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ continuous?

@FShrike Thank you, I applied your suggestion and further clarified the question.

I see my mistake : ) My deleted answer assumed (and this was very silly) that $\partial f/\partial x$ is continuous along the $y$ direction... at just one point

No problem :) Try again!

I'm not sure about the general case but if $f(x,y) = a(x)+b(y)$ or $f(x) = a(x)b(y)$ then this is fairly trivial.

@sudeep5221 can you please delete your comment? people keep upvoting it and i worry they mistake your comment for a solution, which it is not. i just want to reduce confusion, it is not personal

@cnikbesku Done. No worries, I get it.

@sudeep5221 Thank you! :)

Yes, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is necessarily continuous. Using $g$ and $h$ as defined in your question: Let $H$ be any second antiderivative of $h$ with respect to $x$. Integrating $h$ twice, we find that $f$ admits the form $$H(x, y) + j_{1}(y)x + j_{2}(y) \quad \text{for some} \quad j_{1}, j_{2}.$$
We're given that this function is continuous; we wish to show that $g = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} H(x, y) + j_{1}(y)$ is continuous too. This begins the goose chase:

$H(x, y)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} H(x, y)$ are both continuous (as integrals of the continuous function $h$). Hence $j_{1}(y)x + j_{2}(y)$ is continuous.
$j_{2}(y)$ is continuous since $j_{1}(y)x + j_{2}(y)$ is continuous along the path $(0, t)$. Therefore $j_{1}(y)x$ is continuous.
$j_{1}(y)$ is continuous since $j_{1}(y)x$ is continuous along the path $(1, t)$.

So $g$ is continuous as desired.
